# Vote-limited votes counting as feedback

Tags: feature-request, support, voting, votes

[If a not-logged-in user tries to upvote or downvote a post, the post gets an anonymous-feedback counter incremented by one.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/238479) Does the same happen if a logged-in user tries to vote on a post but has already hit his daily vote limit? If not, can it?

Comment: FWIW, it never lets my vote "go through" when I've hit my limit (and the number to the side of the arrow doesn't change). So at least publicly, nothing seems to be registered.

Comment: @SAH Right, the anonymous feedback doesn't register visibly either.